# HTML select box - How do I force a disabled select to keep its widest child's width?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble aligning a form that contains rows of "roles" which can be assigned via a dropdown select box. The problem is that there are certain roles that are "read-only" and they are therefore disabled in the form (the first two rows in the picture below are disabled):

[image: problem]

I figured out that the problem is that the disabled rows do not render the other available options. I was wondering if there is someway to force the select box to keep the width of its children even when it is disabled or do I have to do some hack to ensure the widths are uniform for both enabled and disabled select boxes?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer!

Comment: Where's your code? Please update your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: For which browsers does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I would just assign the select a fix width:

```
<select name="my_select_1" style="width:150px;">
   <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
   <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
   <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your solution does indeed keep the select boxes aligned however, I want to try to avoid using a fixed size as the user should be able to make this particular panel wider, so the width has to be adjustable.

Comment: If you post the code of your html & css, maybe I can show you how to make it adjustable....

Answer (score 0):

First off thanks for the suggestions.

I solved the problem by adding class names to each of the "columns" (The 'Role', 'Name' and minus button that can be seen in the question's image):

```
<!-- Container to hold single row of "roles", "names" and "remove" button -->
<div className="role-field-row" key={_.uniqueId("row")} >

    <!-- Added className (React) 'left-col' -->
    <FormGroup className="on-left left-col">
        <ControlLabel>Role</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl className="form-control dropdown">
          { this.getRoleGroupOptions(roleGroup, personRole) }
        </FormControl>
    </FormGroup>

    <!-- Added className 'middle-col' -->
    <AutoSuggestField className="middle-col" />

    <!-- Added className 'right-col' -->           
    <FormGroup className="on-right right-col">
      <ControlLabel>&nbsp;</ControlLabel>
      <ButtonGroup  bsClass="role-remove-container">
        <Button bsSize="xsmall" disabled={ this.props.readOnly }>
          <Glyphicon glyph="minus" />
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </FormGroup>
  </div>
```

I then added the following style rules

```
.role-field-row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.role-field-row div.left-col{
  width:45%;
}

.role-field-row div.middle-col{
  width:50%;
}

.role-field-row div select{
  width:100%;
}
```

Please note that I am using react so certain attributes such as "className='xxx'" render as "class='xxx'" in the browser. The final result of the changes produced this:

[image: fixed form]